# PlayN + Eclipse not working. DependencyResolutionException

Tags: eclipse, playn

I've never used PlayN before. I tried following the direction Google gives for it, but all I get is errors. I'm using Eclipse, I've got Maven installed, and I imported the sample projects  as directed. I keep getting:

```
[INFO] Building PlayN Hello Android 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.playn:playn-hello-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

This is completely meaningless to me. Can someone explain what is going on? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your core's POM is missing, I would recommend that you try to create a new archetype directly from Maven and then try open the project with Eclipse to see if this helps, also you should check that you're using Maven 3, if I remember well Maven 2.X gave some problems creating and building the PlayN archetype.